# Where can I find where to upload my apk file?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

This might sound like a stupid question, but I am really stack about this, 
I want to upload my game to google developer console, the game use the game services. So I want to upload My game to game sevices in google play console.

I just don't know where can I upload my apk file in to the game services. I just can't find it.

Somone know where it placed?

Please help, and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing your **game** (with it's APK) is done separately from setting up and publishing the **game services**. This allows you connect the game services to games on multiple platforms or to existing games which have already been published.

Just publish your game via the standard publish mechanism in the developer console (under `All Applications`, click the **Add new application** button); this allows you to upload your APK.

Once this is done, you can setup and publish the game services (without an APK) from the `Game services` section.

The connection between the game and the game service is established while setting up the game service (via the **Linked Apps** section). There you specify a package name that matches that of your APK and also provide the signature used for signing the APK. This allows your game to access the published game service.

Comment: Thank you! you help me so much!
But what does google play console do with the screen shots I have put in the game services if this is done seperatly?

Comment: Glad to help :) The information you provide for the **game service** is used when your game is viewed in the Play Games app so that it is the same on multiple platforms. The details you provide for you **actual game** is displayed only in the Play Store listing for that app (which is Android specific).

Answer (score -1):

Look, here you can publish a new Android app to the Play Store.

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

Comment: I know, I uploaded some application before, but how to upload an application with game services (the game pad icon below the android icon in the site you wrote), I can't find where to place my apk file.

Comment: Maybe you could find this link useful! https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

Comment: I follow the steps in this link, I can't see where can I upload the apk? how to connect the game service with my apk?